# Find duplicate sub-items from a List(of ParentObject) using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have Window Application in VB.Net. I have following Classes & Enum.

```
Public Class Page
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property PageItems As List(Of PageItem)
End Class


Public Class PageItem
    Public Property ItemName As String
    Public Property mode As Mode
End Class

Public Enum Mode
    Mode1
    Mode2
End Enum
```

In my application I have a `List(Of Page)` property. One `Page` may have multiple `PageItem`and also `PageItem.ItemName` can be duplicated with different modes. e.g. Application can have a `PageItem` with `Mode1` and `Mode2` (Here it's possible that `Mode1` item may in `Page(0)` and `Mode2` item may in `Page(1)`)

My Question is How to find a `PageItems` `List` (Same `ItemName`) which have both `Mode1` and `Mode2` from a `List(Of Page)` property using LINQ ?

Example:

> Page 1 has 3 Items {Item1, Mode1}, {Item2,Mode1}, {Item3,Mode2}
>
> Page 2 has 2 Items {Item1, Mode2}, {Item4, Mode1}

Here I want a `PageItems` list which have both mode `Mode1` & `Mode2`. In the above case the result should be `{Item1, Mode1}, {Item1, Mode2}` (`Item1` have both `Modes`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need "groups of PageItems", I went for that approach:

```
From p In pages From pi In p.PageItems _
 Group By pi.ItemName Into Group _
 Where (New Mode(){Mode.Mode1, Mode.Mode2}).All(Function(m) _
               (From pig In Group Where pig.pi.Mode = m).Any) _
 Select ItemName, PageItems=(From pig In Group Select pig.pi)
```

Note the final `Select` is reducing the available information. If you remove it you get the pages of each group too.

To test this I used your data set except that I had `Item3` with `Mode2` (instead of adding a new `Mode3` to the enumeration) and now to test the answer to your question in the comments I changed the `Item4` to `Item3`, so that there are two groups returned for my above answer.

The answer to "only get a `List(Of PageItems)`" is just a change to the last `Select` line:

```
From p In pages From pi In p.PageItems _
 Group By pi.ItemName Into Group _
 Where (New Mode(){Mode.Mode1, Mode.Mode2}).All(Function(m) _
               (From pig In Group Where pig.pi.Mode = m).Any) _
 From pig In Group Select pig.pi
```

Comment: Seems your answer will work. I have not tested yet answer. can you provide code how can i get only List(Of PageItems) result.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should do it if I understand correctly. It should return all pages which contain page items of type mode1 and mode2. What have you tried so far?

```
from p in pages
where p.PageItems.Any(i => i.mode == Mode1) && p.PageItems.Any(i => i.mode == Mode2)
select p
```

Comment: Doh, sorry that's C# syntax. I'll leave the VB for you - mine's not too hot :-)

Comment: I want PageItems list (Same ItemName) which have both Mode1 and Mode2 from List(Of Page) property using LINQ.

Comment: Hmmm. Think a downvote is a little harsh here given how unclear the question was before clarification with the example. And if it was for giving the wrong language it is surely simple enough to translate to VB. Any justification from the downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

Dim pages As List(Of Page) = New List(Of Page)()

```
    Dim page1 As Page = New Page()
    page1.Name = "Page1"
    page1.PageItems = New List(Of PageItem)()

    Dim pageItem1 = New PageItem()
    pageItem1.ItemName = "Item1"
    pageItem1.mode = Mode.Mode1

    page1.PageItems.Add(pageItem1)

    Dim pageItem2 = New PageItem()
    pageItem2.ItemName = "Item2"
    pageItem2.mode = Mode.Mode1

        page1.PageItems.Add(pageItem2)

    Dim pageItem3 = New PageItem()
    pageItem3.ItemName = "Item3"
    pageItem3.mode = Mode.Mode2

    page1.PageItems.Add(pageItem3)

    pages.Add(page1)

    Dim page2 As Page = New Page()
    page2.Name = "Page2"
    page2.PageItems = New List(Of PageItem)()

    Dim pageItem4 = New PageItem()
    pageItem4.ItemName = "Item1"
    pageItem4.mode = Mode.Mode2

    page2.PageItems.Add(pageItem4)

    Dim pageItem5 = New PageItem()
    pageItem5.ItemName = "Item4"
    pageItem5.mode = Mode.Mode1

    page2.PageItems.Add(pageItem5)

    pages.Add(page2)

    Dim ps = From p In pages From pi In p.PageItems Group pi By pi.ItemName Into gp = Group Where gp.Count() > 1 From pil In gp Select pil
```

Page, PageItem and Mode class are taken from your sample code. The last line will give you the desired result.

Comment: This is only correct when there cannot be two `PageItems` with `mode` `Mode1` for example. The OP explicitly asked for `Mode1` and `Mode2`.